# React and JavaScript: Calling setState() Only Once to Update State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `calculateTotalPages` function below calculates the total pages that will be displayed. Initial value for totalPages state is set to 0. Where should I call setState to update the totalPages state once the `calculateTotalPages` function has calculated and returned the value of total pages? I know setState is not to be called within render().

```
class Items extends Component {
  state = {
    items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7'],
    isLoading: false,
    currentPage: 1,
    itemsPerPage: 3,
    totalPages: 0
  }

  calculateTotalPages = (items, itemsPerPage) =>{
    let getTotalPages;
    const quotient = Math.trunc(items.length / itemsPerPage);
    const remainder = items.length % itemsPerPage;

    if(remainder === 0){
      getTotalPages = quotient;
    }else{
      getTotalPages = quotient + remainder;
    }

    return getTotalPages;
  };

  
  render() {
    const{items, totalPages, currentPage, itemsPerPage} = this.state;
    const getTotalPages = this.calculateTotalPages(items, itemsPerPage)

    console.log(getTotalPages)

    return (
         <div><h1>{getTotalPages}</h1></div>
    )
  }
}

export default Items;
```

Comment: I'd probably do it in `componentDidMount` if possible, and if it only needs to be set once

Comment: This doesn't address your question directly but I want to provide a strong suggestion. Don't store derived data, like total pages, in your component state, this is also considered an anti-pattern. [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state). The total pages is a simple calculation from the `items` and `itemsPerPage` state values.

Comment: Drew, so basically I should simply call the calculateTotalPages function within render and get the value? No need to store it in a state?

Comment: That is exactly correct.

Comment: Thank you. That makes so much sense and I have corrected my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`render` function should be pure.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.

Don't call this in `render` just call in `componentDidmount`

```
componentDidMount() {
this.calculateTotalPages(this.state.items, this.state.itemsPerPage)
}
```

[From the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will
> trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser
> updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will
> be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate
> state.

Then set the state inside the function would be easier.

```
  calculateTotalPages = (items, itemsPerPage) =>{
    let getTotalPages;
    const quotient = Math.trunc(items.length / itemsPerPage);
    const remainder = items.length % itemsPerPage;

    if(remainder === 0){
      getTotalPages = quotient;
    }else{
      getTotalPages = quotient + remainder;
    }

    this.setState({totalPages:getTotalPages}) //set state here

    return getTotalPages;
  };
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! Can I also use an if statement in componentDidMount to check if the state value has changed from the previous one in order avoid executing that function more than once?

Comment: `ComponentDidMount` will only call once. but as we are setting the state in the `ComponentDidMount` method, technically `render` method gets called twice.

Comment: [more about `componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Answer (score 1):

In a class based component you can do this in `componentDidMount()` since this is invoked only once initially after the first render.

In a functional component you can use `useEffect()` Hook with empty array as the second argument.